# Import python file from a copied directory

Tags: python, python-import

I have a python script which I use to run some simulations. Those simulations are defined in another python script (preprocess.py and simulation.py) and since they are managed by a git repo, I copy them to another location before running them, to avoid generating all the output data in the repo.

To do so, I have something like this

vncs.py

```
import os
import sys
import shutil
import distutils.dir_util
import argparse

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", help="Directory where the results will be saved", dest="output")
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", help="Directory containing the scene", dest="input")
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--preprocess", help="Specifies if the preprocess must be executed", dest="preprocess", action="store_true")
    parser.add_argument("-s", "--simulate", help="Specifies if the simulation must be executed", dest="simulate", action="store_true")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Copy the scene
    in_dir = args.input
    index = in_dir.rfind("/")
    out_dir = args.output + in_dir[index+1:]

    print(in_dir)
    print(out_dir)

    shutil.copytree(in_dir, out_dir, dirs_exist_ok=True)

    current_dir = os.getcwd()

    os.chdir(out_dir)
    sys.path.append(out_dir)

    from . import preprocess
    from . import simulation

    if args.preprocess:
        preprocess.run()
    if args.simulate:
        simulation.run()

    os.chdir(current_dir)
```

I basically copy the input directory to the output directory and try to import the preprocess.py and simulation.py files, but it fails with the following error

```
python vncs.py -i ./EnforcedBeam -o ../../
./EnforcedBeam
../../EnforcedBeam
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jjcasmar/projects/VNCS/Scenes/vncs.py", line 32, in <module>
    from . import preprocess
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: What if you just do `import simulation`? Also, consider using importlib for dynamic imports

Comment: I have tried to add the output directory to sys.path and `import simulation` but apparently it can't find the file. Ill test importlib